# Safely handling a buffer from C

Tags: rust

I have a Rust function like this:

```
pub fn get_buffer() -> &[u8] {
    
    // returns *mut c_char
    let ptr = unsafe { get_buffer_from_c_code() }; 
    
    // returns &[u8]
    let buf = unsafe { core::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr as *const u8, 10) };

    buf
}
```

It generates this error:

```
pub fn get_buffer() -> &[u8] {
   |                        ^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
help: consider using the `'static` lifetime
   |
19 | pub fn get_buffer() -> &'static [u8] {
   |                        ~~~~~~~~
```

I understand the error. It makes sense.

Question: should I take the compiler's suggestion and add a static lifetime specifier?

I'm connecting Rust to a C library that allocates memory internally and returns a pointer to it. Later, the C library takes care of de-allocating that memory on its own. I'd like the Rust code to be able to read what's in the memory, but otherwise leave it alone.

Rust is allocating the slice, though, in its own memory, and the slice itself (the pointer and the length) need to be dropped eventually.

Does a static lifetime do what I need it to do? Will Rust drop the slice, but not try to free the underlying buffer?

Comment: "Rust is allocating the slice, though, in its own memory"—no it isn't.  You are creating a slice into C's memory.  Consequently, for the lifetime of that slice, Rust's safety guarantees must be upheld: the memory must not be mutated or freed.

Comment: The easiest/safest solution is to copy the data into a Rust vector and return that. A more performant solution will require more information about how/when exactly the memory is deallocated.

Comment: @eggyal I don't believe that is true. A slice is a pointer + a length. The space for those two elements get allocated on the stack in the slice::from_raw_parts() call in Rust memory. The pointer in the slice points to C memory, but the pointer itself is in Rust.

Comment: Okay, we're in agreement on that.  I just consider the "slice" to be what is pointed at, rather than the reference itself.

Comment: @ccleve: surely C expects to be informed when the caller of `get_buffer_from_c_code()` is done with using the buffer?  Else how else does it know when it's safe to free/mutate the memory?

Comment: @eggyal It's actually part of a big complicated system where the C code calls my Rust code, which in turn calls C. When my Rust code returns then C deallocates stuff. (This whole thing is actually part of a Postgres extension).

Answer (score 5):

> Question: should I take the compiler's suggestion and add a static lifetime specifier?

No. If your function return a static reference then you're promising to your caller that it can keep the reference around (and read through it) as long as it likes, which is only true if the buffer is never deallocated and never modified.

> I'm connecting Rust to a C library that allocates memory internally and returns a pointer to it. Later, the C library takes care of de-allocating that memory on its own.

The solution to this problem depends entirely on *when* the deallocation happens. You need to ensure that there is some lifetime of a borrow such that there is no possibility to cause the deallocation until the borrow ends. You wrote in a comment

> When my Rust code returns then C deallocates stuff.

That's key to picking the solution. That means that the reference should be obtained *when the Rust code is called*. That is:

```rust
extern "C" wrapper_called_from_c_code() {
    let ptr = unsafe { get_buffer_from_c_code() }; 
    let buf = unsafe { core::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr as *const u8, 10) };

    // Constrain the lifetime of the slice to be the duration of
    // this call by passing it through a lifetime-generic function.
    // (<'a> is just for explicitness and could be elided.)
    fn shim<'a>(buf: &'a [u8]) {
        safe_rust_code(buf);
    }
    shim(buf);

    // Now, after the function call returns, it's safe to proceed with
    // allowing the C code to deallocate the buffer.
}

fn safe_rust_code(buf: &[u8]) {
    // write whatever you like here
}
```

`safe_rust_code` can do whatever it likes in its function body, but the borrow checker will ensure it cannot hang onto the `&'a [u8]` slice reference longer than is safe.

The `shim` function exists to ensure that what `wrapper_called_from_c_code` needs (that the slice reference is being passed to a lifetime-generic function and not one that accepts `&'static [u8]`) *inside* `wrapper_called_from_c_code` rather than to explain it as a constraint on another function. I consider this good practice to keep invariants in the narrowest scope possible, to reduce the chances that they're broken by merely editing safe code without reading the comments.

Comment: Actually, after all that shenanigans with the shim, I think you only needed to add a lifetime param to `wrapper_called_from_c_code`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=773a13f48493bed0cb51f68643debcaa

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the buffer in a struct that frees the buffer when the struct is dropped. The struct can then *own* the buffer, much like a `Vec` owns a block of data on the heap. When it hands out references their lifetimes will naturally be tied to the lifetime of the struct.

```
pub struct Buffer {
    ptr: *const u8,
    len: usize,
}

impl Buffer {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            ptr: unsafe { get_buffer_from_c_code() },
            len: 10,
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for Buffer {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            free_buffer_from_c_code(self.ptr);
        }
    }
}

impl Deref for Buffer {
    type Target = [u8];
    
    fn deref(&self) -> &[u8] {
        // SAFETY: The C library must not modify the contents of the buffer
        // for the lifetime of the slice.
        unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts(self.ptr, self.len) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

The solution I ended up going with was something like this:

```
pub fn get_buffer<'a>(foo: u32) -> &'a [u8] {
    let ptr = unsafe { get_buffer_from_c_code() };
    let buf = unsafe { core::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr as *const u8, 10) };
    buf
}
```

Adding a parameter and then defining a lifetime on the function itself works. Essentially, it says that the returned slice lives as long as the foo parameter.

You can also do this:

```
pub fn get_buffer(foo: &u32) -> &[u8] {
```

If foo is a reference then you can elide the lifetime. The system makes the slice live as long as the foo reference. I don't know why it can do this with a reference and not a value parameter, but there it is.

Comment: Neither of these is safe. They both allow the caller to pick the lifetime, but the lifetime of the buffer is dictated by the C library, not by the caller. Be wary of assuming your code is safe just because you've eliminated the compile errors. When you use `unsafe` that's no longer a valid heuristic. The borrow checker can't catch a mismatch between the Rust and C lifetimes.

Comment: In the first one the caller could pick `'a = 'static`, and in the second one they could pass in a reference to a global `u32` with `'static` lifetime.

Comment: Mark the function `unsafe` if the caller is responsible for upholding safety invariants. Otherwise, when you have a safe function it must be safe *no matter what*, even if the caller uses it incorrectly and doesn't follow the documented rules. When it's possible to misuse a function and break memory safety by the rules of Rust you must mark it `unsafe`.

Comment: My and @KevinReid's answers both encapsulate the unsafeness. Our answers require you, the implementor of `Buffer`, to uphold the constraint: "The C library must not modify the contents of the buffer for the lifetime of the slice." In my answer you must ensure the buffer is never modified when callers have a `&Buffer` shared ref because they can get a slice from a `&Buffer` at any time. Kevin's answer keeps tighter control of when slices are handed out, eliminating a footgun. It's impossible for the C library to modify the buffer when the slice is live (unless it's multithreaded).